# Failed to connect to postgresql database with new created user

Tags: postgresql

After create a new user in my postgresql server with this commands:

```
#su postgres
CREATE ROLE kleber WITH LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE kleber WITH PASSWORD '...';
```

i try login with this user with this command:

```
# psql -U kleber -W
```

but I get this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "kleber"
```

what i am missing here?

Comment: Why are you using -W option of psql here when you have a password associated to the user kleber ?

Comment: with ou without it, i am unable to login with that user.

Comment: `-W` asks psql to not to prompt for the password. If you want to use it use with pgpass file (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:
`psql -h <hostname> -d <database name> -U <user>`

On executing this command you will be prompted to enter the password for your user, kleber in this case. Enter the password for user kleber and this should work.